# Limit of the voltage and current of my electronic product for CE certification

Tags: power-supply, voltage, certification

I would like to know if there is a regulation that would require me to get my product certified because it uses to much power or uses a too high voltage.

My product uses an external adaptor AC-DC that transforms the standard AC (230V) into DC. I want to avoid to use an internal power adaptor because of the certification issue i would face.
This adaptor is CE certified.

If my product voltage usage is less than 30V and the power is about 100W.
I could in a different configuration go above 30V but always less than 50V.

**Is there a voltage or power limit that inforce me to get my product certified?**

Thank you

Comment: You should be OK with the low voltage directive but laws on electromagnetic compatibility might trip you up.

Comment: You should get the standard document you want to comply and read it. This is the only to to know *for sure* what is required.

Comment: If your market requires certification, then it requires certification regardless. That certification might be easier (lower cost) if you use a certified AC-DC adapter. But you'll still have to be certified for issues like fire safety and EMC.

Comment: @Andyaka thank you, yes I m aware of the EMC I had some troublesome experience in the past. I'm more worried about the power of this product as i have plenty of space to shield it well.

Comment: @ThePhoton the market does not require anything I believe just the standard EMC for consumers. About the adaptor I hope I can, this is what I would want to do because I don't want any integrated power supply, I 've been down that path in the past and it is a rather painful one ;). However, because of the several different tensions and the power required I'm wondering if I will be limited by a regulation on maximum power with adaptor or maximum current.

Comment: When I say "your market" I mean the regulations in the market (the place or location and group of customers) where you are selling, and what your retailers, distributors, and customers will accept. If your market has some regulations about product safety, then those requirements are part of what your market will accept.

Comment: For example, the industrial market in Zimbabwe might place very few safety restrictions on your products, while the retail market in France will require a CE mark and full compliance with all EU regulations.

Comment: @ThePhoton I see, for now that product only targets EU, in the future mostly USA

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to CE marking it all depends on which directives your product falls under.

The [Low Voltage Directive 2014/35/EU](http://www.conformance.co.uk/directives/full_text/2014-35-eu_bookmarked.pdf) applies to all products which operate between 50 - 1000 VAC and 75 - 1500 VDC.
In your case, as your device is only operating from 30V you shouldn't have to conform to the LVD.

The [EMC Directive 2014/30/EU](http://www.conformance.co.uk/directives/full_text/2014-30-eu_bookmarked.pdf) applies to pretty much all electronic devices today and therefore you will have to make sure your device complies.
*"The Directive applies to products liable to generate electromagnetic disturbance, or the performance of which is liable to be affected by such disturbance, and to fixed installations."*

The [RoHS Directive 2011/65/EU](http://www.conformance.co.uk/directives/full_text/CELEX_02011L0065-20150624_EN_TXT.pdf) affects all electrical and electronic devices and is to limit the hazardous materials used in manufacture as to prevent environmental hazards upon disposal. As long as all your components are RoHS compliant and the PCB manufacturer makes the boards to RoHS compliance then you should be fine. Just remember to get RoHS certificates for every device and process and to keep them stored in case you need them.

The [WEEE Directive 2012/19/EU](http://www.conformance.co.uk/directives/full_text/l_19720120724en00380071_bookmarked.pdf) is not strictly a CE directive, and I'm not sure of the legal implications but I'd recommend looking into it as it concerns how your customers can safely dispose of your device and minimise damage to the environment.

I've just listed the directives which I usually deal with and is true for most electronic devices, however you can find all the CE directives [here](https://cemarking.net/eu-ce-marking-directives/). Depending on what your device is some more may apply to you. Only once you have gone through the appropriate directives and have sufficient evidence can you then CE mark your product.

Comment: And if it's a toy, then it will need certifying even if it uses no power at all.

Comment: @SimonB not a toy, but thank you.

Comment: @Doodle So from your point of view only the LVD one applies? and this one only limits in maximum voltage, without limitation of power? (thank you for the links)

Comment: @dzada LVD will apply to you and you're correct there is no power limitations. However, the EMC directive still applies to you and if you get caught you can get a fine up to $2.2 million

Comment: Also if you plan to sell into the EU then your device _must_ be RoHS compliant, as of next week, it will be illegal to sell a device into the EU that is not RoHS compliant and the same is true for the WEEE directive. [Here is a list of the penalties and fines for breaking RoHS and WEEE](http://www.goodbyechain.com/pdf/weeerohsfines.pdf)